# include file from different levels in hierarchy with php

Tags: php

I am creating a browser/text-based game. In order to organize the files, I broke them down into different folders

> > Game
> >
> > > Server //DB Connection Files
> > >       Styles //CSS Files
> > >       Structure //Any Template files for the viewable pages (menu bars, etc that I don't want to copy in each viewable .php**
> > >       Scripts //JS Files
> > >       Location Folders // Like 'Work' or 'Crime' - the menu options

If I'm in say **localhost/game/work/work.php** and want to access the database, I would have to use

```
include "../../server/dbc.php";
```

I have tried

```
$root = dirname(__file__);
```

in my **localhost/game** folder before, but it started giving me an error - "failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found" which is because it's using a full file location and you apparently can't do that.

Is there an easier way to make it so I can access my DB from anywhere regardless of hierarchy in the folders?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're really set on doing everything yourself, you can use `set_include_path('/path/to/config/folder');` (You can also set this in your php.ini file if you don't have any centralized file that would be leveraged in every request) Then you can just `include "dbc.php";` But I do love me some PHP frameworks to keep me from re-inventing wheels.

Comment: @CodeGodie I tried `include $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/game/server/dbc.php";` and it does not throw an error, but also doesn't reach that file, which has an `echo` on it so I know if it's reached.

Comment: same effect. Echoing both the 'http_host' and 'server_name' yields "localhost", but neither seem to link up to `include` the folders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a many options, I'll provide a few in order of ease of implementation:

- Leverage `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
- Append your app source path to the [PHP include path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)
- Define a constant (like `APP_PATH`) in a bootstrap/config file
- Read about [autoloading in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) and [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/)

Comment: I used the document_root and it works great! Thank you!

Comment: 4 minutes to accept answer, I'll check back later - thank you again!